# Hangman game letter guessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

that plays hangman game.
I guess a have an error in my `guessWord(word)` function, because its not working properly, and I'm not getting why?
the file for `readDictionary` contains rows of words for the game. but in the main code `words` can also be used.

current output:

```
Welcome to the hangman game.
You will be guessing words, one letter at a time
Guess a letter
a
Would you like to guess a new word? Y/N: y
Guess a letter
h
Would you like to guess a new word? Y/N: g
You guessed 2 words out of 2
```

desired output:

```
Your guess so far: -------
Guess a letter from the secret word: a 
Good guess;
Your guess so far: -A----A
Guess a letter from the secret word: e 
Wrong guess
--------
|

Your guess so far: -A----A
Guess a letter from the secret word: s 
Wrong guess
--------
| 
O
#and so on…
```

---

here are the parameters to do:
readDictionary() which reads the accompanying file “dictionary.txt” and returns a list of all the words appearing in the file.

• guessWord(word) which runs the user interface for guessing the word passed as argument, as described above. guessWord() calls hangmanSketch() with the appropriate argument, whenever a wrong guess is entered by the player.

Note that, even though all the words in the are in all-capital letters, the player should be able to enter the guesses in lower case.

The function returns True, if the player manages to guess the whole word before making 8 wrong guesses. The function returns False, if the player makes 8 wrong guesses and does not guess the whole word.

Below is an extract of a sample run of the whole application, showing the interface for successfully and unsuccessfully guessing words.

---

code:

```
from random import choice


def readDictionary():
    file = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    return list(lines)

def hangmanSketch(n):
    if n <= 0:
        pic = '''  --------\n'''
        return pic
    pic = hangmanSketch(n-1)
    if n == 1:
        pic += '''  |\n'''
    elif n == 2:
        pic += '''  O\n'''
    elif n == 3:
        pic += '''_/'''
    elif n == 4:
        pic += '''|'''
    elif n == 5:
        pic += '''\_ \n'''
    elif n == 6:
        pic += '''  |\n'''
    elif n == 7:
        pic += '''_/'''
    elif n == 8:
        pic += ''' \_ \n'''
    return pic


def guessWord(word):
    while True:
        print("Guess a letter")
        userGuess = input()
        userGuess = userGuess.lower()
        if len(userGuess) != 1:
            print("Please enter a single letter")
        elif userGuess in word:
            print("letter already guessed, try another")
        else:
            return userGuess



def main():
    print("Welcome to the hangman game.")
    print("You will be guessing words, one letter at a time")
    words = readDictionary()
    words = ['ABANDON', 'INQUIRING', 'LACROSSE', 'REINITIALISED'] # use this list if you don't manage to implement readDictionary()
    nAttemptedWords = 0
    nGuessedWords = 0
    play = "Y"
    while play == "Y":
        secretWord = choice(words)  # random choice of one word from the list of words
        nAttemptedWords += 1
        if guessWord(secretWord):
            nGuessedWords += 1
        play = input("Would you like to guess a new word? Y/N: ")
        play = play.upper()
    print("You guessed", nGuessedWords, "words out of", nAttemptedWords)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you having one `while` for iterating between words and inner `while` for iterating through player's guesses:

```
import random

WORDS = ['abandon', 'inquiring', 'lacrosse', 'reinitialised']


def guessed_word(word, guessed_letters):
    """ Build guessed word. E.g.: "--c--r" """
    result = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed_letters:
            result += letter
        else:
            result += '-'
    return result


print('Welcome to the hangman game.')
print('You will be guessing words, one letter at a time')
play = 'y'
while play == 'y':
    word = random.choice(WORDS)
    guessed_letters = []
    hp = 8
    while True:
        print(f'Your guess so far: {guessed_word(word, guessed_letters)}')
        letter = input('Guess a letter from the secret word: ')
        if letter in list(word):
            print('Good guess')
            guessed_letters.append(letter)
        else:
            print('Wrong guess')
            hp -= 1

        if hp == 0:
            print('You loose!')
            break
        elif len(guessed_letters) == len(set(word)):
            print(f'You win! The word is: {word}')
            break

    play = input('Would you like to guess a new word? y/n: ')
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the hangman game.
You will be guessing words, one letter at a time
Your guess so far: --------
Guess a letter from the secret word: a
Good guess
Your guess so far: -a------
Guess a letter from the secret word: b
Wrong guess
Your guess so far: -a------
Guess a letter from the secret word: c
Good guess
Your guess so far: -ac-----
```